# What is Matplotlib's alternative for countplot from seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data:

```
male      843
female    466
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

I plotted bar plots for the same using `countplot` from `seaborn`, and it worked.

But I would like to know what could be its alternative in `matplotlib`.

**I did:**

```
sns.countplot(x = 'Sex', data = complete_data)
```

It gave me:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Say you have this data:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Sex" : np.random.choice(["male",  "female"], size=1310, p=[.65, .35]),
                   "other" : np.random.randint(0,80, size=1310)})
```

You can plot a countplot in seaborn as

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x="Sex", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Or you can create a bar plot in pandas

```
df["Sex"].value_counts().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Or you can create a bar plot in matplotlib

```
counts = df["Sex"].value_counts()
plt.bar(counts.index, counts.values)
plt.show()
```