# Count of different objects in a column and plotting the data

Tags: python, pandas

Total Newby to Python.

I have a EV Car dataset that I have read from a csv file.
I want to do a count number of sales for each brand (column name is "Make") and then plot them against each other.
E.g.
Dataset contains approx.. 105,000 rows of data with 10 different brand names
E.g.  Tesla could occur in 40,000 rows
VW could occur in 30,000 rows
Kia could occur in 35,000 rows

The data in each row is an object as per .dtypes. see screen shot.

I think I have gotten the dataset to the required state.
I have done some of the basics.
Created a DataFrame, sorted the data, checked for duplicates, removed blank data.

My first few lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('seaborn')
```

This is as far as I have gotten from the analysis point of view

```
brand_sales = EVs_by_Population.groupby('Make')
brand_sales.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Nothing happens
thank you

[not sorted but you get the idea of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiEgG.png)
[Data Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsqJd.png)

Comment: I think you are looking for either a seaborn [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) if you dont mind using that or, if you need it to be matplotlib plot, you will need to use `value_counts` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667185/what-is-matplotlibs-alternative-for-countplot-from-seaborn)

Comment: I tried this but it still does not work:
plt.figure(figsize = (15, 5))
ax = sns.countplot(EVs_by_Population = EVs_by_Population, x='Make',  order = EVs_by_Population.groupby('Make')['Model'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).index, orient = 'v')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
labels = EVs_by_Population.groupby('Make')['Model'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).values
# plt.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels = labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Comment: the first part of the error: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-12ddfb2b700f> in <module>
      2 plt.figure(figsize = (15, 5))
      3 
----> 4 ax = sns.countplot(EVs_by_Population = EVs_by_Population, x='Make',  order = EVs_by_Population.groupby('Make')['Model'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).index, orient = 'v')
      5 
      6 # Rotating the x data labels (Vehicle Manufacturer) by 45 degrees and

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make it complicated by grouping the data. I am giving an example below. Please see if this is what you need.

**DATA**

This will create a simple one column dataframe with few car brands

```
import pandas as pd
data=['Volvo']*10 + ['Tesla']*5 + ['BMW']*3 + ['Jaguar']*8
df=pd.DataFrame({'Make':data})
```

**Plotting - Seaborn**

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(data=df, x='Make', order = df['Make'].value_counts().index)
```

**Output plot**

[image]

**Plotting - Matplotlib**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
counts = df["Make"].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.bar(counts.index, counts.values)
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]

**Another attempt with your data**

Here is the data with 5 rows you provided below...

[image]

Running this code...

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(data=EVs_by_Population, x='Make', order = EVs_by_Population['Make'].value_counts().index)
```

...will give you this plot. Is this not what you are seeing?

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million for your help but that did not work.                                                            
The first block of code did not work I am assuming that I would replace data with the name of my data frame (EVs_by_Population) and replace "df" with a new name in my code.                                                                                                                                           this is what I did: EVs_by_Brand=pd.DataFrame({'Make':EVs_by_Population})

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-30b1cd6abb8d> in <module>
----> 1 EVs_by_Brand=pd.DataFrame({'Make':EVs_by_Population})

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    527 
    528         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 529             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    530         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    531             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

Comment: Try `sns.countplot(data=EVs_by_Brand, x='Make', order = EVs_by_Brand['Make'].value_counts().index)`. Assuming the dataframe is the inital dataframe **without grouping** of the data... just your basic dataframe. The data in my example was there because you have not shared your data

Comment: how do i share my data

Comment: You dont need to share the full data. In the question, paste the output of your `EVs_by_Brand` dataframe... may be 10-15 rows

Comment: EVs_by_Population is my original datAframe. I then tried to create another data frame based on your code above.     df=pd.DataFrame({'Make':data}) I replaced the "data" in your code with my original dataframe which is EVs_by_Population and the replaced your "DF" with a new name in my code: EVs_by_Brand.

Comment: No don't... thats where I think you are making a mistake. You should NOT groupby the data. If there are 100 rows of volvo and 200 rows of tesla, that is the correct dataframe that should be fed as input to a countplot, not the grouped dataframe

Comment: TESLA MODEL Y Snohomish Bothell WA 2022 BEV 0 208382779 POINT (-122.21061 47.83448) PUGET SOUND ENERGY INC
KIA NIRO Skagit Anacortes WA 2020 PHEV 42 147041520 POINT (-122.61214 48.51748) PUGET SOUND ENERGY INC
VOLVO XC90 Pierce Auburn WA 2018 PHEV 31 172530641 POINT (-122.17663 47.32326) PUGET SOUND ENERGY INC||CITY OF TACOMA - (WA)
HYUNDAI KONA Grant Moses Lake WA 2020 BEV 415 120622008 POINT (-119.2771 47.13196) PUD NO 2 OF GRANT COUNTY
TESLA MODEL 3 King Kent WA 2018 BEV 346 225967150 POINT (-122.23741 47.3807) PUGET SOUND ENERGY INC||CITY OF TACOMA - (WA)

Comment: so all I have done with the original dataset is : _____ 1. check for null values. _____ 2. replaced some with "no Data" text and _____  3. deleted the lowest number rows that had nulls. _____ I had to do this as part of my project. _____ Hopefully I have inputted your code correctly: _____ sns.countplot(data=EVs_by_Population, x='Make', order = EVs_by_Population['Make'].value_counts().index). _____ It did not work _____  This is the first part of the error code _____  -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

Comment: I have taken your data above and plotted it. Check the section under **Another attempt with your data**

Comment: Thank you Redox. you have saved my sanity. _______ I have the graph I need _______How do I make my graph bigger tough. _______ I was trying this _______ plt.figure(figsize = (50, 20))_______

Comment: Yes, I believe that would work. If not, you can also use `sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(50,20)})`